# how to use return method in Java

Tags: java

Create a class called SumTheNumber.  Within this class make a main method.  This method should define 3 integer variables.  Initialize this variable to the value whatever value you want. Make a static method called sumTwoNumbers which returns integer and takes two parameters. The return value should be sum of two variable that was initially initialized from the main method. In main method provide the output as

The sum is ……….. (Whatever the value was returned from method)

java

```
/**
 * Write a description of class SumTheNumber here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class SumTheNumber
{    
public static void main(String[] args){

    int a =3;
    int b =11;
    int c =2;
    int total = a + b;
    //int sumTwoNumbers = c + b;

    System.out.println("The sum is " + total);

}
public static int sumTwoNumbers (int b ,int c){

    int sum = b + c;
    return sum; 
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if my code correct for what he ask.

Comment: you need to initialize only two variables and store the sum in third vatriable in main method, call the "sumTwonumbers()" function before the print statement and print the value returned by the function and not total  .                                                              it `int value_returned  = sumTwonumbers(int a,int b);`

Comment: Please note that this community is about programming questions, not basic programming *education*. You have to understand that we expect a certain amount of research prior asking a question. And any good tutorial or book will tell you on the first pages how to write and invoke such a method.

Comment: Well everything seems fine, but you need to call the method at one point.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the static method `sumTwoNumbers()` with passing the two integers `sumTwoNumbers(b, c)` to the `total` and then print it.

```
public class SumTheNumber
{    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int a = 3;
       int b = 11;
       int c = 2;
       int total = sumTwoNumbers(b, c);

       System.out.println("The sum is " + total);
    }

    public static int sumTwoNumbers (int b, int c) {
       int sum = b + c;
       return sum; 
    }
}
```

Else, you can directly print with `System.out.println()` as follows,

```
System.out.println("The sum is " + sumTwoNumbers(b, c));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call the method from the System.out.println

```
System.out.println("The sum is " + sumTwoNumbers(b, c));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 types of methods.

1. with return type and take arguments
2. with return type and no arguments
3. no return type and no arguments
4. no return type and take arguments

You are using the 1st type of method.
Here int is the return type and int,int are the arguments.

This means that whenever you have to call the method you have to pass two values, for ex. methodName(5,10).

But since your method is returning a value, it needs to be either stored or passed somewhere else.

```
 int total = sumTwoNumbers(a,b);//now total will have the sum of a and b
  total = sumTwoNumbers(c,total);// now total will have a+b+c
  System.out.println("Sum is "+total);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class SumTheNumber {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 3;
    int b = 11;
    int c = 2;
    int total = sumTwoNumbers(b , c);

    System.out.println("The sum is " + total);
}

public static int sumTwoNumbers(int b, int c) {
    int sum = b + c;
    return sum;
}
```

}